# Configuring latexmk to use a preprocessor (lhs2TeX)

Tags: latexmk, lhs2tex

I want to preprocess an input file before compiling it with, say, pdflatex.

I found one way to do this using the "internal" specification described in the [latexmk manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/latexmk/latexmk.txt), but I expected there to be a simpler and more flexible way using custom dependencies.

I'm using the preprocessor [lhs2TeX](http://www.andres-loeh.de/lhs2tex/) (version 1.18.1) with the file extension `.lhs`. My latexmk version is 4.37 (2 July 2013).

### The "internal" way

A document `input.lhs`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
%include polycode.fmt
\begin{document}
Hello, |world|! % The | and | are used by lhs2TeX.
\end{document}
```

The `.latexmkrc`:

```perl
push @generated_exts, 'tex'; # Remove generated .tex on clean-up

# Use subroutine to do preprocessing and running pdflatex
$pdflatex = 'internal mylatex %B %O';
sub mylatex {
  my $base = shift @_;
  my $tex = "$base.tex";
  # Run the preprocessor
  system('lhs2TeX', '--poly', '-o', $tex, "$base.lhs") == 0 or return $?;
  # Run pdflatex
  return system('pdflatex', @_, $tex);
}
```

At the command line:

```
$ latexmk -silent -pdf input.lhs
Latexmk: Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
Latexmk: calling mylatex( input -interaction=batchmode -recorder )
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
```

This successfully produces an appropriate `input.pdf`. But it also required me to hardcode `pdflatex`.

### A failed attempt using custom dependencies

The `.latexmkrc`:

```perl
$cleanup_includes_cusdep_generated = 1; # Remove generated .tex on clean-up

# Set preprocessor as a custom dependency
add_cus_dep('lhs', 'tex', 1, 'run_lhs2TeX');
sub run_lhs2TeX {
  my $base = shift @_;
  # Run the preprocessor
  return system('lhs2TeX', '--poly', '-o', "$base.tex", "$base.lhs");
}
```

The rule created here never fires. I'm guessing this doesn't work because latexmk doesn't use dependencies for the initial inputs, only for files included within other files (e.g. via `\input`).

### Conclusion

Is there a *simple* way, possibly similar to the above custom dependency attempt, to configure latexmk to use a preprocessor? It shouldn't require hardcoding the compiler. (I could do this with a Makefile, but if I'm using latexmk anyway, then I would prefer to do everything with latexmk.)

Answer (score 6):

You can make either solution work:

1. With your first solution (with the internal subroutine to run `lhsTeX` and `pdflatex`), arrange to add a line to the `.fls` file to inform `latexmk` that the `.lhs` file is an effective source file for running `pdflatex`.  A suitable `.latexmkrc` file is

   ```
   # Use subroutine to do preprocessing and running pdflatex
   $pdflatex = 'internal mylatex %B %O';
   sub mylatex {
     my $base = shift @_;
     my $tex = "$base.tex";

     # Run the preprocessor
     system('lhs2TeX', '--poly', '-o', $tex, "$base.lhs") == 0 or return $?;
     # Run pdflatex
     my $return = system('pdflatex', @_, $tex);
     system "echo INPUT $base.lhs >> $aux_dir1$base.fls";
     return $return;
   }
   ```

   I would also delete the line putting `tex` in `@generated_exts`.  The `.tex` file is too important to `latexmk` for it to be useful to treat the `.tex` file as generated.
2. With the custom dependency solution:

   1. In the `.latexmkrc` file, remove the line setting `$cleanup_includes_cusdep_generated`.  This is important.  For creation of the custom dependency rule, the output file of the custom dependency needs to exist, so that `latexmk` knows that there is something to make. So removing the `.tex` file prevents `latexmk` from discovering the need for a custom dependency.
   2. Before your first run, apply `lhs2TeX` manually to create the `.tex` file. This primes the process of `latexmk` detecting the dependency between the `.lhs` and `.tex` files.

Better solutions can be made, but the ones I can think of need use of `latexmk` internals or modifications to `latexmk`.

Comment: I decided to go with using `make` to run the preprocessor. Solution #1 is not simpler, still hardcodes the compiler, and (as I realized later) runs `lhs2TeX` every time the compiler is run (e.g. the multiple times for BibTeX) when it should only be run once to produce the `.tex` file. Solution #2 still requires an external run of `lhs2TeX`. Lastly, it was more clear how to preprocess `\input`-ted files with a `Makefile` than with `latexmk`.

Comment: Too bad there not a more convenient solution was found.

Comment: Is there any plan to enhance `latexmk` to include this use-case?