# How to use a linter with latexmk?

Tags: latexmk

How can I configure latexmk to run a linter or two such as [lacheck](https://ctan.org/pkg/lacheck) or [chktex](http://www.nongnu.org/chktex/)?

Answer (score 5):

Add this to the end your `.latexmkrc` to cause latexmk to run your linters first and then your regularly-specified `$pdflatex`:

```
sub run_chktex {
  my $name = shift;
  if ( $silent ) {
    system "chktex -q -v0 $name";
  }
  else {
    system "chktex $name";
  };
}

sub run_lacheck {
  my $name = shift;
  system "lacheck $name";
}

sub lint {
  my $fname = shift;
  # lint
  run_chktex $fname;
  run_lacheck $fname;
  return system(@_);
}

$pdflatex = "internal lint %S $pdflatex";
```

We use [John Collins’ answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/143009/94878) for the bulk of the `lint` routine and [mhp’s question on `makeglossaries`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60204/94878) (answer validated by Collins) for the `run_chktex` routine (`lacheck` has no such options).